# Why doesn't bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh resetting my application?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Matthias, thanks for the information about `kafka-streams-application-reset.sh`, but
it does not appear that it has the effect of resetting the state of the world (for
a particular Application ID) to the beginning.

Here is the code that defines the guts of my stream operation graph:

```
private KStream< Long, TsdbObject > rollUpMetricToAllParents( KStream< Long, TsdbObject > input_stream ) {

    KStream< Long, TsdbObject > result_stream = null;

    // Map the input stream into another stream < "timestamp":ancestor_assetId, metric_value >
    // and then group by the key so that groups consist of all the values at a particular
    // time for all assets that have a common ancestor...
    KStream< String, Double > asset_values_keyed_by_parents =
            input_stream.flatMap( new groupByTimeAndAllParentsMapper() );

    asset_values_keyed_by_parents.print( Printed.toSysOut() );

    KGroupedStream< String, Double > asset_values_grouped_by_parents =
        asset_values_keyed_by_parents.groupByKey( Serialized.with( Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double() ) );

    // And sum up all the values in each group (timestamp:ancestor)
    KTable< String, Double > sums_of_groups_by_parents = 
            asset_values_grouped_by_parents.aggregate( new SummerInitializer(), new SummerAggregator(),
                    Materialized.with( Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double())  );

    // Convert the result of the aggregation into a stream of TsdbObjects
    KeyValueMapper< String, Double, KeyValue< Long, TsdbObject > > mapper = 
            new RollupMetricStreamMapper();
    result_stream = sums_of_groups_by_parents.toStream().map( mapper );

    result_stream.print( Printed.toSysout() );

    return result_stream;       
}
```

In context, this method is called passing the input_stream `active_power`.

Tail of print operation prior to reset:

```
...
[KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010]: 1517461200000, TsdbObject [timestamp_ms=1517461200000, value=415455.3004360199, tags_to_values={assetId=303967}]
[KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010]: 1517461200000, TsdbObject [timestamp_ms=1517461200000, value=331916.46723365784, tags_to_values={assetId=2}]
[KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010]: 1517461200000, TsdbObject [timestamp_ms=1517461200000, value=329964.34125709534, tags_to_values={assetId=0}]
```

Perform reset:

```
> bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh --application-id TsdbObjectRollUp --input-topics active_power
Reset-offsets for input topics [active_power]
Following input topics offsets will be reset to (for consumer group TsdbObjectRollUp)
Topic: active_power Partition: 0 Offset: 126
Done.
Deleting all internal/auto-created topics for application TsdbObjectRollUp
Done.
```

> > > Why is the offset of input topic active_power being reset to 126 instead of 0?

Re-run application

Tail of print operation after reset:

```
...
[KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010]: 1517461200000, TsdbObject [timestamp_ms=1517461200000, value=461617.00048446655, tags_to_values={assetId=303967}]
[KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010]: 1517461200000, TsdbObject [timestamp_ms=1517461200000, value=379054.23027038574, tags_to_values={assetId=2}]
[KSTREAM-MAP-0000000010]: 1517461200000, TsdbObject [timestamp_ms=1517461200000, value=377102.10429382324, tags_to_values={assetId=0}]
```

Note that the values are greater than for the previous run, before the reset.  Why are the results the same?  What kind of state is not getting reset?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the offset of input topic active_power being reset to 126 instead of 0?

The tool does a "seek-to-beginning" thus, I assume that older data was deleted already and 126 is the smallest available offset in the topic.

About the changed result:

Resetting an application consists of two parts as explained in the docs: https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html Did you clean up your local state via `KafkaStreams#cleanUp()`?

This blog post explains the details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/